# Javascript Clock output text style

Tags: javascript, html

I have a clock on my website written in javascript which I got from the internet and modified it slightly to fit my needs better and it looks great on firefox using a mac, but when I use it in other browsers on a PC or Mac it looks terrible and I have no idea how to change it, I'm fairly new to javascript. The code i'm using is below:

```
var alternate=0
var standardbrowser=!document.all&&!document.getElementById
```

if (standardbrowser)
document.write('')

function show(){
if (!standardbrowser)
 var clockobj=document.getElementById? document.getElementById("digitalclock") : document.all.digitalclock
 var Digital=new Date()
 var hours=Digital.getHours()
 var minutes=Digital.getMinutes()
 var dn="AM"
  if (hours==12) dn="PM" 
   if (hours>12){
    dn="PM"
   }
   if (hours==0) hours=0
    if (hours.toString().length==1)
    hours="0"+hours
     if (minutes<=9)
      minutes="0"+minutes
      if (standardbrowser){
       if (alternate==0)
        document.tick.tock.value=hours+" : "+minutes+" "+dn
   else
    document.tick.tock.value=hours+"   "+minutes+" "+dn
}
else{
 if (alternate==0)
  clockobj.innerHTML=hours+" : "+minutes
 else
  clockobj.innerHTML=hours+" : "+minutes
}
alternate=(alternate==0)? 1 : 0
setTimeout("show()",1000)
}
window.onload=show

I am looking to be able to set the font and size of the clock to be uniform across most browsers if not all, i'm not too bothered about IE because to site is terrible in ie anyway and will get round to sorting that out in the future.

Comment: can you add a image of how is beign displayed ???

to upload the image 
http://imageshack.us/

Comment: When you say it looks terrible in other browsers what do you mean? This code just writes out the value of the clock to an HTML element.

Comment: In firefox on a Windows machine made the numbers very pixelated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS to do this.  Your clock is being displayed in a container with an ID of `digitalclock`.  That means you can define [style rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/html40/present/styles.html#h-14.2) in an external stylesheet, inline or in the `<head>` of your .html file:

```
#digitalclock {
    font-size: 1em;
    font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;

    color: red;    
    /* and whatever other rules you want */
}
```

Comment: Brilliant thank you, it came to me straight afterward that it wasn't in the js that the styling goes. But I couldn't figure out where thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you just style the containing html element (#digitalclock) via css?